# Cannot add MSCOMCTL.OCX to VB6, no issues with Office

Tags: vb6

I know, there are countless threads about this control already and I've been reading them for hours.  I can't add get this ocx to load into VB6, running 64 bit Win 7.

Things I have already tried:

```
1. unregistering and re-registering (used regsvr32 from syswow64)
2. Did the regtlib msdatsrc.tlb thing I've found
3. Reinstalled sp6
4. Installed the cumulative update everyone is saying is the latest version
```

I haven't reinstalled VB6, I don't have the media at work or I would have, but this has shown to never be the solution to this problem on the successful fixes I've read about these past few days I've been working on this.

Things to note that people aren't talking about in the other threads: I can add the ocx to Office without issue, then add controls (treeview, imagelist, etc) and use them fine.  I can't add the OCX to a new, empty VB6 project.  Most users are trying to open existing project, which fails for me as well, but never say whether they can add the OCX to a new project.  I can't.

I hate to create another one of these threads to further muddy the water, but the solutions in other threads haven't been working for me and no one is mentioning where they can add it to Office or a new project.

This used to work fine months ago, too many things have happened since then to be able to pinpoint one that may have caused this.  My main focus is to be able to add it to a new project again.

Thanks.

EDIT:
VB is being run in elevated XP SP3 compatibility mode.

Comment: You didn't mention running VB as admin/in compatibility mode, did you try that?

Comment: @GSerg yes, it's being run in elevated XP SP3 compatibility mode.

Comment: [This](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/controls/mscomctl/) is kind of old, but you might want to take a look at it.

Comment: When you tried to load the ocx, did you try the browse function and selecting it from your syswow64 folder directly? Does it error when selected? What error - component not registered etc?

Comment: None of the appcompat shims makes any difference with this.  Don't use them, since most of the grab-bag "compatibility modes" add OS version-lies as well causing lots of woes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.  I don't know how it came to be, but I had 3 different versions registered in my registry.  Maybe the version that was trying to be used by VB wasn't compatible but was compatible with Office?  I don't know.

Here's what I did.

I opened up the registry (regedit.exe) and searched for the key 831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1 and found the three different versions were listed.  I made a backup of the sections I was going to change, of course, and then just deleted all of the version entries.  After that, I went back and registered what I had in my syswow64 directory and now it's back to normal.  Rechecking the registry shows I now only have version 2.2 installed.

Comment: I had a similar problem with another ocx control and I also found multiple copies when I browsed my syswow64 folder, selected the newest version, deleted the old ones and all my apps using this control worked fine afterwards.